# When is the attribute's value of a Primefaces component updated?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to understand when and how often an attribute's value is updated. I often see that component's attributes are updated even thought I didn't explicitly call an update on the component.

For example:

```
<p:panel id="panelA"
    styleClass="#{controller.conditionA ? '.styleA' : 'styleB'}"
    rendered="#{controller.conditionB() }">
</p:panel>
```

When the conditionB changes from true to false, the panels *rendered* attribute is updated as well without me calling an updated on the panel with *panelA*.

How are the both attributes *styleClass* and *rendered* evaluated and when?

Are all attributes, which have a non-static value, evaluated and updated periodically?

Instead of the panel, styleClass and rendered there could be other Primefaces components and attributes. I am interested in the general mechanism behind that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: @Jasper de Vries Thanks a lot. I knew about this post, but now I do understand it.

All my components which before inexplicably updated their server-dependent attributes actually had an ajax event with a listener calling the controller. And since process defaults to '@this' for <p:ajax> my component's attribute is updated.